# Estimating an integral involving the n-th power of the cdf of the normal distribution.

Tags: probability, integration, normal-distribution, stochastic-integrals, estimation

I am trying to solve integrals that look like the following:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(cx+d)^n e^{-(x-a)^2}dx$

where $\phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution. I have no idea how to proceed and it would be nice to know the general way to solve this, since I also have to integrate other terms similar to this.

I don't even know if such terms are exactly solvable, but learning how to estimate them would also be really useful for my research.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $c\in {\mathbb R}$ and $d \in {\mathbb R}$. Without the loss of generality we can consider the following integral:
\begin{equation}
f^{(n)}(c,d):= \int\limits_{{\mathbb R}} [\Phi(c x+ d)]^n e^{-x^2} dx
\end{equation}
where $\Phi(x) := P(N(0,1)\le x)=1/2(1+erf(x/\sqrt{2}))$.

Now by differentiating with respect to $c$ we get a following identity:
\begin{eqnarray}
\partial_c f^{(n)}(c,d) &=& -\frac{ n d}{\sqrt{\pi}} \cdot \frac{c}{(c^2+2)^{3/2}} e^{-\frac{d^2}{c^2+2}} \cdot f^{(n-1)}(\frac{\sqrt{2} c}{\sqrt{2+c^2}},\frac{2 d}{c^2+2})+\\
&&\frac{n(n-1)}{2\pi} \cdot \frac{c}{\sqrt{1+c^2} (c^2+2)} \cdot e^{-\frac{d^2}{c^2+1}} \cdot f^{(n-2)}(\frac{c}{\sqrt{1+c^2}},\frac{d}{1+c^2}) \quad (i)
\end{eqnarray}
subject to conditions $f^{(n)}(0,d) = [\Phi(d)]^n \sqrt{\pi}$ and $f^{(0)}(c,d)=\sqrt{\pi}$.

Likewise by differentiating with respect to $d$ we obtain the following identity:
\begin{eqnarray}
\partial_d f^{(n)}(c,d) = \frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2+c^2}} \cdot e^{-\frac{d^2}{c^2+2}} \cdot f^{(n-1)}(\frac{\sqrt{2} c}{\sqrt{2+c^2}},\frac{2 d}{c^2+2}) \quad (ii)
\end{eqnarray}
subject to conditions $f^{(n)}(-\infty,d) = 0$ and $f^{(0)}(c,d)=\sqrt{\pi}$.

Now, integrating $(ii)$ over $d$ from minus infinity to $d$ we obtain:
\begin{eqnarray}
f^{(0)}(c,d)&=& \sqrt{\pi}\\
f^{(1)}(c,d)&=& \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\left(1+ erf[\frac{d}{\sqrt{c^2+2}}] \right) \\
f^{(2)}(c,d)&=& \sqrt{\pi} \left( \frac{1}{2} (1+erf[\frac{d}{\sqrt{c^2+2}}]) - 2 T(\frac{d \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{c^2+2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+c^2}})\right) \\
f^{(3)}(c,d)&=& \frac{3}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-4 \text{erf}\left(\frac{d}{\sqrt{c^2+2}}\right) T\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} d}{\sqrt{c^2+1} \sqrt{c^2+2}},\sqrt{\frac{c^2+2}{3 c^2+2}}\right)-4
   T\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} d}{\sqrt{c^2+2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+1}}\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{d}{\sqrt{c^2+2}}\right)+1\right)-4 T\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2} d}{\sqrt{\left(c^2+1\right)
   \left(c^2+2\right)}},\left\{\sqrt{c^2+1},\sqrt{\frac{c^2+2}{3 c^2+2}}\right\}\right)\right)
\end{eqnarray}

where $T(h,a):=\int\limits_h^\infty \phi(\xi) 1/2 erf[a \xi/\sqrt{2}] d\xi$ is the Owen's T function and $T(h,\{a_1,a_2\}):=\int\limits_h^\infty \phi(\xi) \prod\limits_{j=1}^2 (1/2 erf[a_j \xi/\sqrt{2}]) d\xi$ .

Note: If we were to integrate $(i)$ over $c$ from zero to $c$ then  of course get the same results as above but in addition get a quite interesting result:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int\limits_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2+c^2}}} e^{-d^2 u^2} erf[\frac{d \cdot u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}] du=\\
&&
%
\frac{2 \sqrt{\pi } \left(e^{d^2} T\left(\sqrt{2} d,\sqrt{\frac{1}{c^2+1}}\right)-T\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} d}{\sqrt{c^2+2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2+1}}\right)\right)}{d}-
\frac{2 \sqrt{\pi } \left(e^{d^2} T\left(\sqrt{2} d,1\right)-T(d,1)\right)}{d}
\\
&&
\frac{3}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \int\limits_1^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+c^2}}} e^{-d^2 u^2} \frac{erf[\frac{d u^2}{\sqrt{3-u^2}}]}{1+u^2} du + 
6 d \int\limits_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+c^2}}} e^{-d^2 u^2} T(\frac{\sqrt{2} d u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-4 u^2}}) du=\\
&&
6 \sqrt{\pi } \left(T\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2} d}{\sqrt{\left(c^2+1\right) \left(c^2+2\right)}},\left\{\sqrt{c^2+1},\sqrt{\frac{c^2+2}{3 c^2+2}}\right\}\right)-T(-d,\{1,1\})\right)+\\
&&
3 \sqrt{\pi } \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{d}{\sqrt{c^2+2}}\right) T\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} d}{\sqrt{c^2+1} \sqrt{c^2+2}},\sqrt{\frac{c^2+2}{3 c^2+2}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{d}{\sqrt{2}}\right) T(d,1)\right)
\end{eqnarray}

```
In[2813]:= {c, d} = 
 RandomReal[{-2, 2}, 2, WorkingPrecision -> 50]; n = 3;
T[h_, a_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   phi[xi] Product[
     1/2 Erf[xi/Sqrt[2]   a[[j]]], {j, 1, Length[a]}], {xi, h, 
    Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 30];
 NIntegrate[
 E^(-d^2 u^2)  (Erf[(d u^2)/Sqrt[1 - u^2]]), {u, Sqrt[1/2], Sqrt[1/(
  2 + c^2)]}]
(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])/
  d (E^d^2 OwenT[Sqrt[2] d, Sqrt[1/(1 + c^2)]] - 
    OwenT[(Sqrt[2] d)/Sqrt[2 + c^2], 1/Sqrt[1 + c^2]]) - (
  2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])/d (E^d^2 OwenT[Sqrt[2] d, 1] - OwenT[ d, 1])

3/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])
   NIntegrate[ ( 
   E^(-d^2 u^2)  Erf[(d u^2)/Sqrt[3 - u^2]])/ (1 + u^2), {u, 1/1, 1/
    Sqrt[1 + c^2]}] + 
 6 d NIntegrate[ 
   E^(-d^2 u^2)
      OwenT[(Sqrt[2] d u^2)/Sqrt[1 - u^2], 1/Sqrt[3 - 4 u^2]], {u, 1/
    Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2 + c^2]}]

6 Sqrt[Pi] (T[(-d Sqrt[2])/
     Sqrt[(1 + c^2) (2 + c^2)], {Sqrt[1 + c^2], Sqrt[(2 + c^2)/(
      2 + 3 c^2)]}] - T[-d, {1, 1}]) + 
 3 Sqrt[\[Pi]] (Erf[d/Sqrt[2 + c^2]] OwenT[(Sqrt[2] d)/(
      Sqrt[1 + c^2] Sqrt[2 + c^2]), Sqrt[(2 + c^2)/(2 + 3 c^2)]] - 
    Erf[d/Sqrt[2]] OwenT[ d, 1])



Out[2815]= -0.0114936

Out[2816]= -0.0114935684495970038682633122159256469816612286325

Out[2817]= -0.0215486

Out[2818]= -0.021548550158499122192222419055
```